# GREATEST() & LEAST() functions not working with TIME variables in stored procedure in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL stored procedure calculating employees' working time, overtime etc. On some special case I needed to calculate the overlapping between two periods (the employee's working hours and the company working hours) and I did it using the GREATEST() and LEAST() functions on variables of type TIME.

The stored procedure produced the correct results in MySQL 5.5 but changed behavior when I upgraded to MySQL 5.7. Actually, it works in MySQL 5.7 if I change the variable type to VARCHAR() but the data it works on comes from table fields of type TIME.

Below is a simplified form of the procedure demonstrating the problem.

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `timetest`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `timetest`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE working_from, working_to, open_from, open_to TIME;

  -- This data actually comes from table column of type TIME
  SET working_from = '08:00:00';
  SET working_to = '16:00:00';
  SET open_from = '07:00:00';
  SET open_to = '14:00:00';

  IF open_from IS NOT NULL AND open_to IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET working_from = GREATEST(working_from, open_from);
    SET working_to = LEAST(working_to, open_to);
  END IF;

  SELECT working_from, working_to;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

In MySQL 5.5:

```
mysql> call timetest();
+--------------+------------+
| working_from | working_to |
+--------------+------------+
| 08:00:00     | 14:00:00   |
+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In MySQL 5.7:

```
mysql> call timetest();
+--------------+------------+
| working_from | working_to |
+--------------+------------+
| 07:00:00     | 14:00:00   |
+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `GREATEST` doesn't detect the values as `TIME` values. You can solve this issue by using `CAST(column_name AS TIME)`:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `timetest`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE working_from, working_to, open_from, open_to TIME;

  -- This data actually comes from table column of type TIME
  SET working_from = '08:00:00';
  SET working_to = '16:00:00';
  SET open_from = '07:00:00';
  SET open_to = '14:00:00';

  IF open_from IS NOT NULL AND open_to IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET working_from = CAST(GREATEST(working_from, open_from) AS TIME);
    SET working_to = CAST(LEAST(working_to, open_to) AS TIME);
  END IF;

  SELECT working_from, working_to;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4774db552e268f7d90fe7f4f4128a9b0)

---

This looks like a bug on MySQL 5.7 ([see this bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89979)):

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `test_greatest`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE time_1 TIME;
  DECLARE time_2 TIME;
  DECLARE time_3 TIME;
  DECLARE result TIME;

  SET time_1 = '08:00:00';
  SET time_2 = '07:00:00';
  SET time_3 = '06:00:00';

  -- always returns the last parameter.
  SET result = GREATEST(time_1, time_2, time_3); -- result is 06:00:00
  SET result = GREATEST(time_1, time_3, time_2); -- result is 07:00:00
  SET result = GREATEST(time_2, time_3, time_1); -- result is 08:00:00

  -- using a CAST on first parameter the GREATEST is working.
  SET result = GREATEST(CAST(time_1 AS TIME), time_2, time_3); -- result is 08:00:00
  SET result = GREATEST(time_1, CAST(time_2 AS TIME), time_3); -- result is 06:00:00
  SET result = GREATEST(time_1, time_2, CAST(time_3 AS TIME)); -- result is 06:00:00

  -- using CAST on the whole GREATEST is working.
  SET result = CAST(GREATEST(time_1, time_2, time_3) AS TIME); -- result is 08:00:00

  SELECT result;
END
```

This example always returns the last parameter (`time_3`) of `GREATEST`.